# vmstat command missing

Tags: linux, mips, cross-compiling

I am using a embedded Linux platform (MIPS processor, Linux 2.6.18-6.4, with busy box) & I don't see vmstat command. what do I need to do get this command installed.

I believe it would be application download and cross-compiling it for my platfrom, but where can I find its sources.

Is there any chance that I can get the binary for MIPS ?

Comment: Busybox provides nmeter as a replacement of vmstat: https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#nmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vmstat is included in [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package, You just have to cross compile it. Or enabling vmstat in busybox and rebuild busybox

For a precompiled version the libc and libproc versions have to match. What toolchain are you using?

Comment: ./mipsel-linux-gcc -v                                          Configured with: ../gcc-4.2.0-20070124/configure --prefix=/opt/toolchains/crosstools_hf-linux-2.6.18.0_gcc-4.2-11ts_uclibc-nptl-0.9.29-20070423_20090508/ --build=mipsel-linux --host=mipsel-linux --target=mipsel-linux-uclibc --with-build-sysroot=/usr/src/redhat/BUILD/build_uClibc --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-target-optspace --with-gnu-ld --with-float=hard --enable-threads --infodir=/opt/toolchains/crosstools_hf-linux-2.6.18.0_gcc-4.2-11ts_uclibc-nptl-0.9.29-20070423_20090508/info --with-arch=mips32